# Studying WEP wireless hacking

Tags: arp, wep, aircrack-ng

Studying WEP wireless hacking.
I am curious about the principle of ARP request replay attack

In this attack, if another client sends an ARP packet to the AP, it continues to send the same ARP packet.

When an AP receives this ARP packet, it is said to create a new packet with a new IV and respond.

I received an ARP packet, so why create a new IV?

Isn't there an IV in the original ARP response packet?

I searched for materials and asked questions in the open chat room, but I couldn't get an answer.